# Qt plugin application inside 3rd party application

Tags: qt

I have a Qt application in a DLL that I need to integrate with 3rd party non-Qt Windows applications. I don't own the 3rd party applications and so can't change their core event handling mechanisms (I don't even have the source in some cases). What's the best way of doing this?

I tried the QtWinMigrate framework, but this makes me change CWinApp::Run, which I can't do. If I instead create the QApplication and call exec(), a 2nd event loop gets created. This sort of works, however some of the non-Qt application events now mysteriously disappear (e.g. tooltips and keyboard commands stop working).

Any thoughts much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a clean solution for this (but I might be wrong).

Anyway, you could use `QCoreApplication::setEventFilter` to grab a few key events (for key presses, mouse hover, so on) and feed them to the application event loop. It's ugly, but it might get the job done.

`QCoreApplication::setEventFilter` receives a function with the following signature:

```
bool myEventFilter(void *message, long *result);
```

On Windows, `message` can be static casted to a `MSG`. My knowledge of the Windows API is somewhat rusted but it should not be difficult finding out the related events.

I must stress that I deeply dislike this solution. I'd sincerely would wrote the plugin without using Qt. But it should work, even if in a very ugly way.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I investigated this and it worked in my example app (although I ended up having to set the filter on the QAbstractEventDispatcher instance instead of the QApplication). Needless to say the production environment is quite a lot more complicated, and I ended up having to run the 2 event loops on separate threads (and take extreme care with communication between the 2 applications!). Thanks.

Comment: @Robin Nothing at all. I've also dealt with integrating new Qt code with a MFC legacy application. The trouble with this kind of solution is that it violates Qt premises, like a single event loop and can generate very subtle and hard-to-track bugs. Anyway, real world problems requires real world solutions. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

[QtWinMigrate](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/qtwinmigrate/qmfcapp.html) is the correct solution for this problem. It solves the Qt in Win32 or MFC event loop problem. You do not need to change `CWinApp::Run`

`QMfcApp::pluginInstance` is what you need for a Qt DLL to work with the MFC event loop. You set it up in DllMain:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "qmfcapp.h"

BOOL WINAPI DllMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved )
{
    static bool ownApplication = false;

    if ( dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH ) {
        ownApplication = QMfcApp::pluginInstance( hInstance );
    }
    if ( dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH && ownApplication ) {
        delete qApp;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```